# django formset - dont submit a single form if a checkbox is not true?

Tags: django, forms

I have a formset displayed as a table, and I do not want to validate any of the forms that do not have a specific checkbox ticked. However when the formset is submitted they are getting validated.

Do I need to handle this at the clean_field() method level?

If so how do I stop the form at that point, without rendering the whole formset invalid??

```
class HILISForm(forms.ModelForm):


    summary = forms.CharField(
                widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':3, 'cols':70}),
                label='',
                required=False)


    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ('reported', 'summary', )

    def clean_reported(self):

        reported = self.cleaned_data['hilis']

        if reported:
            return(hilis_reported)
        else:
            raise(forms.ValidationError('Not checked...'))
```

if I 'pass' instead of raising the error- then this form still appears in my cleaned_dict which I do not want.

Comment: If you want to keep the form from being submitted, then you will have to do it client-side. The `clean_field()` method is a function of a submitted form. You could use javascript: jQuery's `$.onSubmit()` method, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a much easier and cleaner way to do it, but if you get stuck you could do it by creating an id for each input field, and then creating/saving the object with your logic in the view instead. It looks like you have a lot of things to check and wouldn't be ideal, but is one way to do it.

I had a tricky validation scheme for one of my projects and found it easier to just create the form, and then process it in the view on post. You can still add error messages to the form and do all of that from the view also.